# Can variables in python be negative? Using SpriteMover and trying to move an image all around an edge of a screen

Tags: python, variables, integer

In an engineering basics class and starting to learn python. My homework assignment is to move an image "iulogo.gif" that is 64x64. I have to move this image on an (640, 480) screen. I need to move this image around the edges of all parts of the screen starting from (0,0), to (640, 0), to (640, 480), and (480, 0), back to (0,0).

My problem is going back from (640, 480) to (480, 0) to (0,0). I am moving by 0.5. When I move forward, I do "x_position += 0.5" and down y_position += 0.5". But when I go backward and down, it says invalid syntax. I type "-= 0.5".

```
    while (1):
            while (x_position < 640):
                    x_position += 0.5
                    sm.write_x(x_position)
                    sm.update_screen()
            while (y_position < 480):
                    y_position += 0.5
                    sm.write_y(y_position)
                    sm.update_screen()
            x_position = 640
            sm.write_x(x_position)
            y_position = 480
            sm.write_x(x_position)
            while (x_position <=  640
                    x_position =- 0.5        #here is the error
                    sm.write_x(x_position)
                    sm.update_screen()
            while (y_position <= 480):
                    y_position =- 0.5        #most likely here too
                    sm.write_y(y_position)
                    sm.update_screen()
            x_position = 0
            sm.write_x(x_position)
            y_position = 0
            sm.write_y(y_position)
```

I expect the output of x_position -= 0.5 to move it backward 0.5, but the output is just a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Use `-=` not `=-`. `a =- 1` is interpreted as `a = -1` whereas `a -= 1` is interpreted as `a = a-1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line above is missing `):` at the end.

Comment: thanks, fixed that. now it says for the first line: "unindent does not match any outer indentation level."

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.